# Idiomatic alternative to reflection

Tags: reflection, rust

I am trying to select a digest algorithm (from rust-crypto) based on a configuration string. In Python or JavaScript, say, I'd probably use reflection to get at this:

```
getattr(Digest, myAlgorithm)
```

...but from what I've been able to Google, this isn't best practice in a language such as Rust (plus I've found no details on how it could be done). My initial thought was to use a pattern match:

```
let mut digest = match myAlgorithm {
  "sha256" => Sha256::new(),
  ...
};
```

However, this doesn't work because, while all the branches of the match implement the same trait, they're ultimately different types. Moreover, presuming there were a way around this, it's a lot of hassle to manually enumerate all these options in the code.

What's the right way to do this in Rust?

Comment: Do you know about *traits* in Rust? They are used to specify a common interface to multiple implementations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since all the algorithms implement the same trait `Digest`, which offers everything you need, you can box all the algorithms and convert them to a common `Box<Digest>`:

```
let mut digest: Box<Digest> = match my_algorithm {
    "sha256" => Box::new(Sha256::new()),
    ...
};
```

Now you don't know anymore what the type was, but you still know it's a `Digest`.

The python and javascript do the boxing (dynamic heap allocation) for you in the background. Rust is very picky about such things and therefor requires you to explicitly state what you mean.

It would be interesting to have reflection in Rust to be able to enumerate all types in scope that implement a trait, but such a system would require quite some effort in the rust compiler and in the brains of of the rust community members. Don't expect it any time soon.

Comment: Thank you: So traits are a little bit like Haskell typeclasses? Anyway, that gets round the type checking problem, but now when I try to use this, I get `the trait \`crypto::digest::Digest\` is not implemented for the type \`Box<crypto::digest::Digest>\``

Comment: huh... that is odd... as a hack you can try to get a reference to the inner object by using `&*digest`. But without knowing more details on what you tried I can't help.

Comment: @Xophmeister What is the definition of `Digest`? The code ker gave will only work if the trait is [object safe](https://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/).

Comment: @LambdaFairy I'm a complete Rust newbie, so the best I can do is [link to the code](https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/blob/master/src/digest.rs)

Comment: @Xophmeister, Yes, traits are like Haskell's typeclasses and trait objects (like `Box<Digest>`) are like ExistentialTypes.

Comment: actually `Box<Trait>` doesn't implement `Trait`, but it implements `Deref<Target=Trait>` which means that you can simply use `&*digest` to get `T:Digest` for a generic function. I'm assuming that's where the error came from